# How to filter by predicate on index in Repa

Tags: haskell, filter, repa

I have two Repa arrays `a1` and `a2` and I would like to eliminate all the elements in `a2` for which the corresponding index in `a1` is above a certain threshold. For example:

```
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R -- for Repa
import Data.Array.Repa (Z (..), (:.)(..))


a1 = R.fromFunction (Z :. 4) $ \(Z :. x) -> [8, 15, 9, 14] ! x
a2 = R.fromFunction (Z :. 4) $ \(Z :. x) -> [0, 1, 2, 3] ! x
threshold = 10
desired = R.fromFunction (Z :. 2) $ \(Z :. x) -> [0, 2] ! x
-- 15 and 14 are above the threshold, 10
```

One way to do this is with `selectP` but I would like to avoid using this, since it computes the arrays, and I would like my arrays to remain in delayed form, if possible.

Another way is with the `repa-array`, but `stack solver` does not seem to know how to import this library with resolver `nightly-2017-04-10`.

Comment: If this is the only thing you need, it would be better to model this as a set of pairs. The order here isn't meaningful, only that specific elements are paired together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at this issue is that, in order to create a Repa Array, you need to know the size (`extent`) of the Array upon creation (eg. `fromFunction`), but, in case of filter operation, there is no way to know the size of the resulting Array in [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) without applying a thresholding predicate, essentially computing values of the resulting Array.

Another way to look at it is, `D`elayed array is a simple function from an index to a value, which is fine for most operations. For filtering though, when you apply a predicate, in order to find a value at a particular index, you now need to know all values that come before that index in the resulting array, cause for any location, a value may be there, maybe not.

[vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package solves this issue elegantly with stream fusion, and [repa-array](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-array), next version of Repa, which is still in experimental stage, seems to be trying to use a similar approach, except with extention to higher dimensions (I might be wrong, haven't looked too closely).

So, short answer, there is no way to do filtering with Repa style functional fusion. Either:

- stick to `selectP` - faster (probably), but less memory efficient (for sure), or
- piggy back onto `ifilter` from `vector` package for sequential
  filtering

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list of pairs with `zip`, then `filter` by a predicate function with the type `(Int,Int) -> Bool` and lastly extract the first or second element of the pair (depending on which one you want) by using `map fst` or `map snd` respectively. Everything you need for this is in Prelude.

I hope this is enough information so you can put the pieces together yourself. If in doubt, look at the type signatures of the functions i mentioned.

Comment: Probably more useful, you can use `mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]` from the `Data.Maybe` module to map and filter at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from my original question, but I am interested in doing this in Repa. These are potentially very large arrays so the prelude list would not be a good option. The Repa library does not seem to have a filter function.